# Android app content updates

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I wrote a super simple android app for a conference using phonegap and jquery mobile. At the last minute, there was a room change. At the time, I had all of the info in the html file, so I could only update it by deploying a new version of the app and hoping everyone updated. How can I make this better for next time? I know I could store the info remotely in an xml file and download it, but I don't want to needlessly use up their data if nothing has changed. What is an efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a super simple service which your app contacts every now and then if there are updates available and if so then download the new infos ... I would say ;-) More elaborate would be using some push services like parse.com offers.

Comment: You mean a service that runs on the phone?

Comment: Oh sorry that might confuse as service is something we more associate with android in this context. What I mean is a service/program on some server. On your phone either the user triggers it himself - pressing a checking for update button or whatever - or you have a service which checks periodically. That was my idea.

Comment: this service just gives back the version number of the latest update information, on the phone you store what update version you have received so far ...

Comment: if you dont have a server or you are not that familiar with server programming give parse.com a try. for the traffic you might generate it should do with what is free on parse.com. Basically you would just have one class there with two columns, the version number and the link to that actual update file. than you query for the highest version number from your android app and if higher than what you have received so far download the file from parse - that is what i do in one of my android apps, it works well and i stay easily within the traffic the free account offers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll check out parse.com, or polish my php skills ;-)

Comment: You are welcome. Parse.com is just the one I stumbled over and it does what i need, I am sure there are plenty others doing the same thing probably better. Of course if you have a server this kind of simple service is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You could host the project on a GIT or SVN repository, and then just tell them to check out/clone your project at the beginning of each session.

That way you can confirm and be sure that they are all running what you want them to run.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that this is not a technical conference. The attendees would not be able to manage this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The app would check out/clone the project from the GIT repository, not the individuals at the conference. Alternatively, you could just release this as a website (or for example, a sub-site of the conference's main website) that users would browse to rather than being a native app on devices. This way, if there are any other changes, you can update the `html` (or whatever language you use) and it would be immediately updated on the website.